# How can I substitute non-float class atom in dataframe column in r?

Tags: r

I got Q for substitution atom in dataframe, column by column.
For example

```
    A_col    B_col
1    "Hi"      0.3
2    -0.5      0.7
3   "HiHi"   FALSE
```

In above table, There are two character class atom in A_column. So It is not float! I want get rid of that two `Hi` and `HiHi`. Or, substitute to `NA`.
And also, In B_column, There is Boolean class atom (`FALSE`). I want still remain Boolean class in this column.

So point is, how can I get rid of atom class type in a column.

Comment: You can't have two classes in a single column i.e. boolean + numeric.  One option is `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.numeric)` it willl automatically convert the non-numeric to `NA` and `FALSE` would coerce to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `data.frame` column cannot have multiple class (i.e. boolean + numeric).  Instead, we can convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric`.  The non-numeric will convert to `NA` while the boolean `FALSE` will coerce to 0.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(replace(x, x %in% FALSE, 0)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A_col = c("Hi", "-0.5", "HiHi"), B_col = c("0.3", 
"0.7", "FALSE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3"))
```